# E:Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found” update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104160/method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-https-could-not-be-found-update-error)

When I try to install something from Ubuntu Software center or synaptic, a message pops up saying

```
E:Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/ did not start correctly
```

After cleaning apt, updating etc, the problem persists. I didn't find nothing strange on my `sources.list`. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. What could be causing this error?

Comment: could you post the output of sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as well as the content of any file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Are you sure this is the same error? The error message is different, referring to the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar when I try running update / upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Driver for method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found
```

But my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file does not have any `https` in it...

Here's the [answer to my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104160/method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-https-could-not-be-found-update-error).

Comment: Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.