# Installing dolphin emulator 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, dolphin

Been trying to install the dolphin emulator program on ubuntu 14.04 with no luck...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin
sudo apt-get update
```

Which tells me this...im not writing out everything unless required...

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/methods/httpe could not be found
```

Yes "E" not "S" in the http'e' part

Thanks ahead of time for looking into this ..I looked all over and couldnt figure it out...btw ...Im new to linux/ubuntu so id prefer the easiest way to understand this

Comment: I really wish people would stop asking for help and putting the site down at the same time, it is very rude. Anyway add your screen shot at http://imgur.com/ and post a link here, also gonna need that whole error message you don't want to type, sorry you have to make a small effort.

Comment: Also first try this `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https` http://askubuntu.com/questions/104160/method-driver-usr-lib-apt-methods-https-could-not-be-found-update-error

Comment: please try ^ suggestion,if not working,Please edit your question and the add the content of  `/etc/apt/sources.list `file

Comment: yea well looks like i need more rep to post that files contents...seriously bs bro..

Comment: http://imgur.com/np9trTL

Comment: btw i wouldnt bash on any part of this site...besides the crap rep feature...people have some serious problems that might even be losing them some serious money...i dont have time to build rep..

Comment: fixed my problem which NO ONE has ever had it seems because I looked litterally EVERYWHERE....all I did to fix it was rename the "https" to "httpe"...why it is asking for E not S is beyond my comprehension...

Answer (score 0):

This problem (Method driver "httpe") if ran into can be solved by going to

/usr/lib/apt/methods then RENAMING "https" to "httpe" for some odd reason the computer changed it to E not S ...its still S keep in mind